# Advice writing a script to test for contamination between cells in a grid

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, automated-tests

I am working with a machine that drops microscopic particles into cells in a plate containing 96 cells (8x12 grid). Occasionally there is cross-contamination between cells as particles intended for one cell fall into an adjacent cell. After the machine is finished we get measurements of the weight in each cell. I'd like to have a script that combines this weight information with the spatial information of the grid of cells to identify potential cases of cross contamination. I am trying to think of the most logical way to do this and any feedback would be much appreciated.

Ideally the script would be implemented in R (dplyr if possible though I am not sure it would be relevant for this kind of task).

The input data looks like this (for first 4 rows of grid):

```
Cell    Weight
A1  2
B1  2
C1  2
D1  2
E1  2
F1  2
G1  2
H1  2
A2  2
B2  0.1
C2  2
D2  4
E2  2
F2  0.1
G2  2
H2  2
A3  2
B3  2
C3  2
D3  2
E3  2
F3  4
G3  2
H3  2
A4  2
B4  2
C4  6
D4  2
E4  2
F4  2
G4  2
H4  2
```

A1-H1 is the first row of the grid of cells, A2-H2 the second etc, on until A12-H12.

So how it looks in reality in the grid of cells is as follows, with the weight measured shown for each cell:

```
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   0.1 2   4   2   0.1 2   2
2   2   2   2   2   4   2   2
2   2   6   2   2   2   2   2
```

For the case above I would like to highlight that cell F3 may contain contamination from particles intended for cell F2 because cell F3 has double the median weight of the other cells and is directly below cell F2, which is almost empty, suggesting that the particles intended for cell F2 may have fallen into the nearby cell F3.

I am not suspicious of cells C4 or D2, because even though they are heavier than expected, I know that particles are not able to fall far from the cell they are intended for, so if the cells directly adjacent to the cell of interest are not unusually depleted in weight then I do no suspect contamination.

I think a tricky part is defining whether a cell has less or more weight than expected, as there is considerable variation in weight between cells due to noise in the weight measurements. I could do a blunt solution such as consider any cell with weight < 1 as empty for this purpose. However I think a better solution would be to calculate the median weight of all the cells and then consider any cells with weight below 10% of the median weight as empty. The contamination check only needs to be carried out on cells that are 1.5x greater than the median weight. I am very open to suggestions on how to deal with this.

The output would ideally be an additional row added to the table. Cells without suspected contamination would have this row left empty. While  any cell that is suspected of containing contamination contains the name of the cell/s where contamination may have come from in this row.

So for this example:

```
Cell    Weight  Contamination 
A1  2   
B1  2   
C1  2   
D1  2   
E1  2   
F1  2   
G1  2   
H1  2   
A2  2   
B2  0.1 
C2  2   
D2  4   
E2  2   
F2  0.1 
G2  2   
H2  2   
A3  2   
B3  2   
C3  2   
D3  2   
E3  2   
F3  4   F2
G3  2   
H3  2   
A4  2   
B4  2   
C4  6   
D4  2   
E4  2   
F4  2   
G4  2   
H4  2
```

Any help on thinking about the best approach to solve this contamination check problem would be greatly appreciated. I am also not sure of an efficient way to convert the column of data into a useful matrix in R, so that for each cell it is clear that the cells directly above and below and left and right should be checked (ignoring missing cells for cells that are on the edges). Currently the data is in a linear form but I assume it must be converted into a matrix for this test to work as intended.

Apologies if this question is poorly structured I have tried to be as clear as possible. I am happy to take any suggestions to make it clearer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without reshaping your data. Assuming your data is called my.data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(my.data)
median.weight <- DT[, median(Weight)]
DT[,
    Contamination := ifelse(
      Weight >= median.weight * 1.5 &
      ((.I %% 8 != 0 & shift(Weight, n=1, type="lead") < 1) | #not in last column, check next value
      (.I %% 8 != 1 & shift(Weight, n=1, type="lag") < 1) | #not in first column, check previous value
      (.I<88 & shift(Weight, n=8, type="lead") < 1) |
      (.I>8 & shift(Weight, n=8, type="lag") < 1)),
      TRUE,
      FALSE
    )
  ]
```

This sets the `Contamination` column to be `TRUE` if that row's `Weight` is 1.5* the median and any of the neighbouring cells have a weight below 1. The `shift` function is used to lead/lag the data by 1 or 8 rows to take advantage of the fact that you have a *8 grid. `.I` stores the current row number in `data.table`.

EDIT: Used modulo operators `%%` to check if in first or last column of grid.

Comment: oh this is very interesting I hadn't come across the shift function, I'll try testing it tomorrow and get back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Threw together something naive that, while relying on an explicit nested loop, allows for contamination from any of the 3–8 neighboring cells (three if it's on a corner, eight if it's in the middle). It also allows for possible contamination from more than one neighboring cell. That said, I am positive there is a more R-like approach that scales much better than this will.

```
weight <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0.1, 2, 4, 2, 0.1, 2, 2, 
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

# for now hardcode number of rows, but if you wanted, you could take
# the maximum numeric portion of the Cell vector
m <- matrix(weight, nrow = 4, byrow = T)

b <- quantile(as.vector(t(m)), c(0.05, 0.95))

# flag cells below/above the 5th/95th percentile, respectively
m1 <- ifelse(m <= b[1], -1, ifelse(m >= b[2], 1, 0))

m2 <- matrix(NA_character_, nrow = nrow(m1), ncol = ncol(m1))

for (i in 1:nrow(m1)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(m1)) {
    if (m1[i, j] == 1) {
      # don't attempt to go out of matrix bounds
      rows <- max(c(i - 1, 1)):min(c(i + 1, nrow(m1)))
      cols <- max(c(j - 1, 1)):min(c(j + 1, ncol(m1)))

      # allow for multiple possible contamination cells
      o <- c()
      for (r in rows) {
        for (c in cols) {
          if (m1[r, c] == -1) {
            o <- c(o, paste0(LETTERS[c], r))
          }
        }
      }

      if (length(o) > 0)  {
        m2[i, j] <- paste0(o, collapse = ";")
      }
    }
  }
}

colnames(m2) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(m2)]
rownames(m2) <- 1:nrow(m2)

data.frame(weight, Contaminates = as.vector(t(m2)))
```

Separately, this flags cells if they are below/above the 5th/95th percentile, respectively. This could be changed to suit your needs.